# Mysql adds new row instead of updating it

Tags: php, mysql

I have integrated google loing to my website. It's working fantastic. When someone logs in via google for the firs time, then a new entry is stored in the database.
But, when he logs in again..only the last login (a column on the table) should be updated...but instead, mysql adds a new row.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
public function trigger_registration_from_google($fname,$lname,$email)
    {
        global $conn;
        try
        {
            if(useremailexists($email))
            {
                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                //run update query
                //user already exists, only update
                try
                {
                    $s = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users set last_login = :last_login where emailid = :email ");
                    $s->bindParam(':last_login',$date);
                    $s->bindParam(':email',$email);
                    $s->execute();
                    $s->closeCursor();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //insert
                //insert now..since he is a new user
                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                $v=1;
                $r="google";
                try
                {
                    $s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,emailid,registeredby,registeredon,last_login,verified) values (:fname,:lname,:emailid,:registeredby,:registeredon,:last_login,:verified)");
                    $s->bindParam(':fname',$fname);
                    $s->bindParam(':lname',$lname);
                    $s->bindParam(':emailid',$email);
                    $s->bindParam(':registeredby',$r);
                    $s->bindParam(':registeredon',$date);
                    $s->bindParam(':last_login',$date);
                    $s->bindParam(':verified',$v);
                    $s->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }//function
```

Edit
**useremailexists**

```
function useremailexists($email)
{
    //check if the email exists
    global $conn;
    try
    {
        $s = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from users where emailid = :email");
        $s->bindParam(':email',$email);
        $s->execute();
        if($s->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}//function
```

Comment: How does `useremailexists()` work?

Comment: Have you checked the output from the function 'useremailexists'? You can remove most of the code and simply test your condition as thats what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Validate if the function useremailexist return true or false , we can't help you without this piece of code.

Comment: That function is working properly.
Updated the question.